# How to type a higher order component with flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have the following HOC:

```
export default (keys: Array<string>) =>
  (WrappedComponent: React.Component<*, *, *>) => (props: Object): React.Element<*> => {
    if (hasNotYetLoadedProps(keys, props)) {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: '100%',
          }}
        >
          <div>Loading</div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return <WrappedComponent {... props} />
  }
```

that either render the original component or a loading indicator. With the actual flow type declaration I get this error:

```
React element `WrappedComponent`. Expected React component instead of React$Component
```

in the last line. What would be the correct type of the incoming component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type needs to `ReactClass<any>`

```
export default (keys: Array<string>) =>
  (WrappedComponent: ReactClass<any>) => (props: Object): React.Element<*> => {
    if (hasNotYetLoadedProps(keys, props)) {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: '100%',
          }}
        >
          <div>Loading</div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return <WrappedComponent {... props} />
  }
```

Comment: Hi, could you develop a little your answer ? What's the difference between React$Component, ReactClass, React$Element ?
Note : here is an example of typing for an HOC that returns a class, and that seem to work thansk to your answer
`export const someHOC = (SomeComponent: ReactClass<*>): Class<React$Component<*, *, *>> => (
  class extends React.PureComponent { ... `

Comment: Apparently, ReactClass throws away type checking: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2159